# Best way for Scheduing jobs using C# and Sql server and Quartz.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, cron, quartz.net

I have to create a Quartz.Net Scheduler in the C#. Scheduling the firing time from data stored in the Sql Server. Please suggest me what would be the better approach for dynamic scheduling.

I will appreciate if there is any article for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple tutorial:

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html